# Cakephp 2.0 I am using HABTM relation but intermediate table model not fetching associated data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

For example i am having tenders table and consortiums table, and for HABTM i created intermediate table tenders_consortiums. now for my requirement i created a model TendersConsortium

```
class TendersConsortium extends AppModel {

/**
 * Use table
 * @var mixed False or table name
 */
public $useTable = 'tenders_consortiums';

/**
 * Display field
 * @var string
 */
public $displayField = 'counsortium_id';

//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed
/**
 * belongsTo associations
 * @var array
 */
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Tender' => array(
        'className' => 'Tender',
        'foreignKey' => 'tender_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Counsortium' => array(
        'className' => 'Counsortium',
        'foreignKey' => 'counsortium_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

}

But when i fetch pagination data  `$this->paginate('TendersConsortium', $TendersConsortium_cond)` it returns

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'TendersConsortium' => array(
            'id' => '6',
            'tender_id' => '3',
            'consortium_id' => '3',
            'state' => 'Winner',
            'created' => '2012-08-08 12:21:28'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'TendersConsortium' => array(
            'id' => '7',
            'tender_id' => '3',
            'consortium_id' => '1',
            'state' => 'Winner',
            'created' => '2012-08-08 12:21:28'
        )
    )
)
```

i have also set recursive level 2 but not getting the associated data from tenders and consortium table.

Comment: Did you set the hasMany relation in tender and consortium models? See this particular section for Habtm with more than just foreign key in tables http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through

Comment: Where's your pagination settings array, update the question with it.

Comment: Thanks, Hugo Dozois your link is helpful to me, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through

Helpful